# MongooseJS using find to find by reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this Mongoose Schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , dev      = require('../db').dev();

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  company: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Company'
  },
  questionnaire: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Questionnaire'
  }
});

module.exports = dev.model('Survey', schema);
```

I want to find only the surveys which have a specific company id. How do I do that? I tried (with my Express handler):

```
app.get('/survey', function(req, res) {
  Survey.find({ company: req.query.company })
        .populate('questionnaire')
        .exec(function(err, surveys) {
                return res.json(surveys);
        });
      });
```

Comment: Assuming `req.query.company` is an ObjectId string, this looks fine.  What's not working about it?

Comment: It is the correct objectId. The find returns an empty array when trying to use the company condition. But with no conditions, returns the entire collection. Including the document with the company id I was looking for in the first place.

Comment: Something is not as it seems.  Is it possible that the `company` property in the document you're searching for is actually a string and not an ObjectId in the database?

Comment: It is a string in the database. Mongoose does some magic with it when it populates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your latest comment you say that the `company` field of the `Surveys` collection is actually a string and not and ObjectId and that's why this isn't working.  Because your schema definition declares `company` as an ObjectId, Mongoose will cast your `req.query.company` value to an ObjectId and then query for documents in `Surveys` where their `company` property is an ObjectId with the same value.  So if `company` is a string in the database it won't match.

If you update the `company` values in `Surveys` to be ObjectIds instead of strings then this will work.

Comment: Thanks. Worked. I was just baffled that populate works either way.

Comment: @ChristofferHallas how exactly did you get this to work? Which changes did you do in the database? I have the exact same problem

Comment: @CommonCoreTawan probably change to `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.requery.company)`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `'company._id`

```
app.get ('/survey', function (req, res) {
  Survey.find ({ 'company._id': req.query.company }).populate ('questionnaire').exec (function (err, surveys) {
    return res.json (surveys);
  });
});
```

Comment: I haven't no, but I did now and It didn't work, I liked the idea though, I now also tried 'company.ref' etc, but these are just the fields of the object that specify the type in the database, not the actual value. When I look through the data in the mongo CLI, it appears to be a string.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (and it is hinted in the accepted answer) was to make sure that the documents are created through mongoose (i.e through your express server) because this will force the schema onto them, and thus the ids will be stored as objectIds.

Initially I had created a document manually through the database using the objectIds as simple strings, and this causes the query not to work because mongo casts the id (from your server) as an ObjectId.